# What part is this and how do I create it in Fusion 360?

Tags: software, computer-aided-design

I am new to Fusion 360 and I am trying to create a plastic part that snaps onto a plastic tube (torus in Fusion 360).
Unfortunately, I am not sure what the name of the plastic part is, and I have been trying to Google something for the past half hour, with no luck.

Below is my best drawing attempt. The curved snap-fit part is the one I want to create. The longer tube is just there to show the other part being attached to it.

Can someone please identify the part (the keywords I should search for on Google) and direct me to some resources on how to create it in Fusion 360? Thank you.

[image]

Here is the closest picture I could find:

Its description on Google was "Durable Aluminum Alloy Golf Shaft Adapter Sleeve Accessory F9 Casing Scheduler, Connector", but I am not sure which keywords are relevant to my use case here.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a picture of the real part? This drawing actually doesn't help to understand.

Comment: I wish I could tell you the name of the part. I'm sure if I knew what it was called, I could figure out how to create it without asking on here. Not sure who to ask to figure out the name of the part, so I posted on here. Could you direct me to better resources where I can figure out the name of the part?

Comment: I am trying to create a torus ring, and when you push this part on the ring, it snaps onto the ring. And likewise, you can unsnap it by pushing on the opposite end of the part. I am trying to think of real-world use cases, but nothing is coming to mind.

Comment: I just added a picture of the type of part I am trying to describe. Does that ring any bells for the name for you?

Comment: Something along the lines of half tube or snap tubing. The way to draw probably is. Extrude one tube and later cut based on same plane. Or Extrude already in the final form.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a short section of "snappit" pipe cover?